# Solana Pay Get Signature

Tags: web3.js, solana-pay

I created a transfer request link with reference parameter for solana pay.

```
solana:8X5zHADZ4oTZXC59JmjVn1NRqcA6DGc649TrwL11ZdNr?amount=0.0001&reference=Fc7aCzx4uVaaFAU8RqYRQXwpdi3sR67b3rvuT9wuq2rR&label=Shop&message=Thanks%20for%20all&memo=OrderId123
```

After transaction is completed, i run getSignaturesForAddress method with my reference key in web3.js, but it return 0 signature.

How can check signature after transaction is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findReference` from `@solana/pay` which will make this a bit easier: https://docs.solanapay.com/api/core/function/findReference

But fundamentally you're doing the right thing, you need to look for transactions that include your reference key.

In terms of why it's not working, are you using Phantom wallet by any chance to scan the code and send the transaction? There's currently a bug in their transfer request handling where the `reference` isn't being included as part of the transaction so this logic isn't working. Try using another wallet and see if that fixes it for you.

You can verify if the transaction includes the reference key you expect too, if you look it up in explorer, for example by searching the address of your wallet that's making the payment. That's the signer of the transaction so it'll definitely be there. If your reference is not included then that's a bug in the wallet.